# How can Rpi3B configure an I2C PN532 module as a NFC tag, to send data to an Android smart phone?

Tags: pi-3b+, nfc

I'm working on a NFC study.
My development environment is as follows.

- raspberry pi 3 B
- PN532 NFC : https://www.sunfounder.com/pn532-nfc-module-for-raspberry-pi.html
- Android Phone (app name :nfc-tools)

I connected the PN532 NFC to my raspberry pi using i2C, referring to the link below.
http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=PN532_NFC_Module_for_Raspberry_Pi

Since then, when I contacted the plastic tag that was bundled with the PN532 NFC, I have received something as follows.

[image]

What I want is the PN532 NFC in my raspberry to be the tag, and the android phone to be the reader.
I've run several examples provided by libnfc and nothing happens in the android app (nfc-tools).
(Of course, if you contact Android with the round plastic tag that is included in the bundle, it will read something.)

I have some questions in this situation.

1. Does my PN532 NFC module work with an NFC tag?
2. Is there a sample code or reference site that can operate the PN532 NFC module as the NFC tag?
3. Do you have any android app to recommend when developing RPI-based NFC?

I'm currently only aiming for communication.
So I just need to pass the data on the raspberry pi and receive the data on the android phone.

I hope there is someone who can help me.
Note that the language uses C.

Addition

@tlfong01,
Thank you for your reply.
Have you ever used another NFC module?
I'm thinking maybe my NFC module is a problem.

Below is my clearer situation.
I must operate the Raspberry Pi with the NFC Tag.

What I want is raspberry pi to act as NFC Tag, like a credit card.
When I touch the NFC module on the raspberry pi with the Android phone, a particular app is executed (such as YouTube, for example).

my development environment is as follows.
- LG V30
- raspberry pi 3 B
- raspbian : 2019-07-10-raspbian-buster-lite
- NFC : PN532 module (https://www.sunfounder.com/pn532-nfc-module-for-raspberry-pi.html)

I've wired the raspberry pi and PN532 Module with i2c and proceeded according to the guide below.

http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=PN532_NFC_Module_for_Raspberry_Pi

I performed nfc-pool as in the guide above, and it worked well when I contacted my credit card.
But I'm trying to get my raspberry pi to work with an NFC Tag like a credit card.

So I tried doing nfc-emulate-tag among the samples provided by libnfc.
As a result, the following error occurred.

pi@raspberrypi:/proc $ nfc-emulate-tag
nfc-emulate-tag uses libnfc libnfc-1.7.1-223-gf8b2852
NFC device: _PN532_I2c opened
nfc-emulate-tag will emulate this ISO14443-A tag:
ISO/IEC 14443A (undefined baud rate) target:
    ATQA (SENS_RES): 00  04
* UID size: single
* bit frame anticollision supported
       UID (NFCID3): 08  ab  cd  ef
* Random UID
      SAK (SEL_RES): 09
* Not compliant with ISO/IEC 14443-4
* Not compliant with ISO/IEC 18092

Fingerprinting based on MIFARE type Identification Procedure:
* MIFARE Mini 0.3K
* SmartMX with MIFARE 1K emulation
Other possible matches based on ATQA & SAK values:
NFC device (configured as target) is now emulating the tag, please touch it with a second NFC device (initiator)
error   libnfc.bus.i2c  Error: read only -1 bytes (265 expected) (Input/output error).
nfc_target_init: Success
nfc_target_emulate_tag: Success
error   libnfc.bus.i2c  Error: wrote only -1 bytes (10 expected) (Input/output error).
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Failed to transmit data. Retries left: 2.
error   libnfc.bus.i2c  Error: wrote only -1 bytes (10 expected) (Input/output error).
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Failed to transmit data. Retries left: 1.
error   libnfc.bus.i2c  Error: wrote only -1 bytes (10 expected) (Input/output error).
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Failed to transmit data. Retries left: 0.
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Unable to transmit data. (TX)

Then my PN532 module wend dead.

I checked where the error came from and it's happening in "nfc_target_init.
This function is described as "Initialize NFC device as an emulated tag."

I am looking for anyone who has tried NFC Tag using raspberry pi with PN532 or anyone who can advise me about this situation.

I am grateful for your enthusiasm
Thank you.

Comment: Hi @chacha, Welcome and nice to meet you. Your question is a little bit confusing. Let me summarize: (1) What you have successfully completed is "Rpi controlled I2C NFC module reading the tag."  (2) Now what you want is "Rpi controlled PN532 NFC module to be tag, and android phone to be reader". Let me do some brainstorming: (a) Let Android phone use a BlueTooth serial app to talk to a cheapy Bluetooth serial module, which is connected to the PN532 module which talks SPI/I2C/UARTserial. Then you send AT/serial commands to BT module which relays your commands to control PN532 module. / to cont.

Comment: In the above gang of three config, (a) You don't need your old friend Rpi, (2) BT module can stay perhaps 10+ feet wireless from Android, and PN532 module can be 200+ feet serial wired from BT module. Another config is to let Rpi talk to PM532 module using SPI, and use WiFi etc to talk to Android phone. Just quick and dirty brain storming suggestions. Cheers.

Comment: References: AliExpress SunFounder US$28 NXP PN532 3V3 SPI/I2C/UART NFC Module for Rpi: 
(1) Datasheet: https://www.sunfounder.com/pn532-nfc-module-for-raspberry-pi.html,
(2) Tutorial: http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=PN532_NFC_Module_for_Raspberry_Pi

Comment: Hi @tlfong01, 
Thanks for the quick answer.
Sorry that the question is not clear.

As you understand, what I want is the RPI PN532 NFC module to act as an NFC tag and the android phone to act as an NFC reader.
My current project is not considering Bluetooth, and should only use NFC. When this communication is complete, I will work on my post-project work.

What I need is to make the RPI PN532 NFC module an NFC tag and receive that tag in the Android NFC-tools App.
I'm using an app called NFC-tools in the store without creating an android app.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi @chacha, Ha, sorry, perhaps it is me confused between RFID and NFC, and I forgot that my SamSung Android smart phone can also be a NFC device. Please ignore my comments above, because myself have not a clear mind, mixing thing up. I think I need some time, perhaps one or two days, to clarifying things myself, before I come back to give more clear comments. See you tomorrow or day after tomorrow.  My apologies. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, I remember one thing related to Anroid phone and NFC device. I have a Rapoo A500 NFC/BlueTooth dual connection mode speaker. I don't like using NFC, because BT is easier. Now I know why I might have confused: My Rapoo NFC speaker is a NFC device, NOT A RFID TAG, so no need to use any service or app. In other words, I think similarly,  PN532 NFC module can be configured to be a NFC device and "connect" to the Android phone, but NOT configured as a RFID tag. But I am only 20% sure, perhaps I would think harder. / to continue, ...

Comment: PS - References: (1) https://www.androidheadlines.com/2015/01/featured-review-rapoo-a500-bluetooth-speaker.html, 

(2) https://www.techwalls.com/rapoo-a500-bluetooth-portable-speaker-review/,

(3) http://rapoo.com/article/51. Please feel free to ask me to try any SamSung Galaxy C9 Pro NFC and Rapoo NFC speaker. They are on my desk! :) Ah, I also have a couple of NFC/RFID readers in hand. I can also try what you suggested. Cheers.

Comment: Just now I skimmed the 200 page datasheet of the PN532 NFC chip and found that the chip can be configured as a "CARD", I guess it means a RFID tag: Ref: "NFC PN532 User Manual (200 pages!)- NXP", 
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/141520.pdf

3.1.3.5 Target/PICC Mode: This mode is the one used when the PN532 is configured as target or ISO/IEC14443-4 card, 
3.1.3.6 Virtual Card mode. Perhaps you can google for a "config PN532 NFC as a RFID card" library :) Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01, I added my situation to the original to clarify my question.
If you have experienced or know, please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I am not so confused now. But there are still a couple of things I need to clarify. I must first confess that I have very little experience with NFC stuff, except what I told you, using my Samsung Galaxy smart phone to connect my Rapoo A500 NFC/Bluetooth wireless speaker. Actually both connections were unreliable, and I end up using the audio 3.5mm male to male connector to connect to A500 speaker. These days I am using my SamSung Galaxy C9 Pro to connect to another BlueTooth Speaker, a Creative brand BlueTooth speaker, connection smooth and reliable.

Comment: I do have a couple of PN532 NFC modules to test out things. My goal is to gain some basic NFC knowledge and skills. Let me propose a learning plan.  Be warned that I am a NFC newbie and at the same time a hobbyist programmer.  I do have ninja level I2C hardware and software knowledge and skills. Now let me search my junk box for the old modules which are collecting dust, read the manuals, and perhaps repeat/reproduce your libNfc experiments. I don't mind frying one or two cheapy NFC modules.  I hope you also don't mind me going very slowly, and very likely misunderstand what your are saying.

Comment: Now I have inserted a photo of my two versions of NFC module. The TaoBao shop selling me these cheap toys says the one in red is the improved V3. So I think I should test the red guy first.

Comment: Now I am taking a close look at the red guy (Fig 2), with a note.  Comments welcome.

Comment: We need to agree on the technical terms on NFC. I have inserted two references from AdaFruit to the list of my answer. Please let me know if you have other good reference, or tutorials, or forum discussions for newbies like me.  Many thanks.

Comment: Just now I read the AdaFruit catalog and understand your requirement: it is the third function described below: :PN532 NFC/RFID controller breakout board - v1.6": 
https://www.adafruit.com/category/55
The PN532 is the most popular NFC chip, and is what is embedded in pretty much every phone or device that does NFC. It can pretty much do it all, such as (1) read and write to tags and cards, (2) communicate with phones (say for payment processing), and (3) 'act' like a NFC tag.

Comment: I must confess that I never though about the PN532 module CAN ACT LIKE A TAG. So that is the root cause of my confusion. It is 100% my ignorance fault, not yours. Anyway, now I have more confidence to try out your requirement, because it is one of the specified functions.

Comment: Hi @chacha.  Long Time no see.  In case you are still interested, libNFC can actually do card emulation: https://github.com/frankmorgner/libnfc/blob/master/examples/nfc-emulate-tag.c. Cheers.