# RFID reader/writer

Tags: rfid

I'm creating a clocking in system for work and I'm considering using a raspberry pi for the card interface. Having never used one before I just want to check if this is possible. I've seen a few things about how to read the cards but I can't find details on how to write the cards.

Are you able to write RFID cards from a raspberry pi and can you point me in the right direction if so?

Thanks.

Comment: search for *raspberry pi rfid writer* and you'll find there's plenty of products to choose from, and equally plenty of tutorials

Comment: A group of "my" middle school kids did that as a project.  See Jaromanda X's advice about searching.  Get everything working with a breadboard, then use one of these to make the connections permanent: https://www.adafruit.com/product/571  You'll need a suitable case, too.

Comment: This tutorial looks good: "How to setup a Raspberry Pi RFID RC522 Chip (Level - Beginners) - Gus, PiMyLifeUp 2019oct03 ": 
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/.

Comment: thanks all. I'll have a read of that tutorial. I think Ive been confused thinking a reader and writer were different things but looking at these I think it might be the same thing in some circumstances.

Comment: Ha, yes, I was also confused, when I tried to answer the following question: 
How to configure PN532 RFID module as a NFC tag ..." (Note: Read the chat record): "https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108502/how-can-rpi3b-configure-an-i2c-pn532-module-as-a-nfc-tag-to-send-data-to-an-and".  I knew the PN532 module can read and write RFID card, but I did not know that the module can also PRETEND/FAKE as a NFC/RFID card/tag. In other words, it can do three things, (1) Read, (2) Write, (3) Pretend to be a card/tag.

Comment: (1) RECOMMENDATION: the PyMyLifeUp SimpleMFRC522 python library is the best I have so far tried. (2) WARNING: Other libraries using C are out of date, and no longer supported by the authors.